# Why do you need administrator rights to burn an iso to an sd card?

Tags: windows, administrator, iso-image, sd-card

Whenever I want to burn an image file to an SD card, I require administrator rights to do so. Why is it like that on Windows?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @gronostaj, I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing files to an SD card and deleting partitions (low level access) is not the same thing from a security perspective.

Being able to delete and create a partition could potentially provide a route for what is known as [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) because it means that a user could effectively wipe permissions and controls from an entire drive that might have been set up by an administrator.

So, just as changing folder permissions for protected folders requires administrator rights, so to does low-level access to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a big deal in a home setting but in a business environment it certainly would be. The ability to create or obtain access to an image of a drive you do not have admin access to would be a serious security risk. Hackers have expended a great deal of effort to obtain much less. A hacker with a standard account could make an image backup of a shared computer and with the image have complete and unrestricted access to every unencrypted file on the computer, including those containing potentially sensitive information.

For that reason the ability to create image backups requires admin level access. And where security is important it is vital to properly control access to backup images.